# Run time Error while using facebook framework in iOS 6.0

Tags: ios6

I started the project in "ios 5.0".and i used facebook framework.That time its not giving me any error in the run time.

After I upgraded my device to "ios6.0" and downloaded the new version of xcode. i am able to build and run it on the simulator.But i am not able to run it on iPhone.
Can anyone please explain me why its happening?And why app is running in simulator.but      not in iPhone/

Basic diff bwtween architecture of simulator and iPhone?

Thanks&Regards
Vijay

Answer (score 1):

Because ios 6 has new framework which is social framework, so just add it.after adding it you dosent need to make so many methods for facebook ,twitter...

https://github.com/yashesh87/Social-Framework-iOS6
this link will help you..